# Spring MVC ajax file upload error

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I've got a Spring MVC REST controller to handle .zip files upload, like

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/browser/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String getUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("path") String path) {
     //do something
 }
```

I use this configuration for MultipartFile:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    filterMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(17000000);
    return filterMultipartResolver;
}
```

My HTML upload form is

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/rest/visualization/browser/file" id="hdfsLoader">
    <span class="pull-right">
        <input name="file" class="filestyle" id="zipUpload" data-input="false" type="file" data-buttonText="Upload" data-classButton="btn btn-primary" data-classIcon="icon-plus">
    </span>
</form>
```

and I use ajax POST request to send data:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append( "file", $('#zipUpload')[0].files[0]);
var path = $('#hdfs_path').val(); //some external value
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: form.attr("action") + "?path=" + path,
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: (function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    })
});
```

I've tested this code on 3 different .zip files.
On **15.8 MB**-size file everything works fine.

On **9.72 MB** I've got `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream closed`

On **701 KB** it is `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:186 - Handler execution resulted in exception: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: If I remove the configuration for MultipartFile (Bean), I am able to load only small .zip files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted my bean for MultipartFile and added these 3 lines to my application.properties and this solved my problem:

```
multipart.enabled=true
multipart.max-file-size=-1
multipart.max-request-size=-1
```